# match local recipients in virtual_alias_maps

Tags: postfix

I want to redirect all local mail by specifying an address in virtual_alias_maps file.

It is possible to match recipients with regexp, but it's too complex. They can be:

- no domain (`root` etc.)
- `root@localhost`
- `root@myserver`

Here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=107671 they try to match `/.+@.+\.localdomain/` , which of course doesn't work.

Postfix already has `$mydestination` config parameter. Can I match with it somehow?

**Upd:** tried `local_transport = virtual:` , but virtual cannot forward.

Perhaps a global `.forward` file will help?

Comment: What do you mean by "all local mail"?

Comment: @masegaloeh I mean mail that would be normally delivered to local users by postfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `virtual_alias_maps`, use `alias_maps` instead.

- Parameter `virtual_alias_maps` match all address classes
- Parameter `alias_maps` match only local address class i.e. address defined in `mydestination` parameter

See [Address Class README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) for more information.

---

So, the parameter of `alias_maps` would become

```
#main.cf
alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/catch-my-local

#/etc/postfix/catch-my-local
/.+/   my.forwarding.address@example.net
```

---

Alternatively, you can put `forward_path = /etc/postfix/global-forward` in `main.cf`. Basically, you override the path of `.forward` file for EVERY user.

In `/etc/postfix/global-forward` just put

```
my.forwarding.address@example.net
```

No need to specify the left side mapping.

[Credit to OP](https://serverfault.com/questions/701233/match-local-recipients-in-virtual-alias-maps#comment867410_701245) for this workaround.

Comment: Alternatively `forward_path = /etc/postfix/global-forward`